# Почему не работает цикл while {}?

Tags: while, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему `while{thread.sleep(1)}` работает, а `while{}` нет. Разве программа не должна компилироваться также?

```
public class Just_tell_me_why {
static int [] list = new int[51];
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    counter.start();
    while (list[50]!=50){

    }

    for (int x:list) System.out.print(x + " ");

}
public static class Counter extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i]=i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Disabled77 а как вы поняли, что цикл не работает?

Comment: При запуске программы это строчка не работает -  for (int x:list) System.out.print(x + " ");

Comment: @Disabled77, так что все-таки происходит?

Программа не завершается и "висит" в `while (list[50] != 50);` часами? И эта ситуация стабильно воспроизводится?

Answer (score 1):

Переменные, доступ к которым осуществляется из разных потоков, должны быть объявлены, как volatile.

В вашем случае

```
volatile static int [] list = new int[51];
```

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов: Что толку, что ссылка на массив объявлена как `volatile`? Это не сделает `volatile` _элементы_ массива.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов: Дубликаты объекта не будут создаваться никогда в любом случае без явного вызова `new`.

Вы можете привести ссылку на конкретный абзац документации, который гарантирует, что объявление **ссылки** на массив как `volatile` гарантирует _happens-before_ для _элементов_ массива?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов: Ещё раз: а где именно там про _элементы_ массива? Там я вижу лишь консистентность вида разных потоков на ссылку на массив, но не на его элементы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите ерунды. Массив и его элементы не разделимы. Если Вам непонятно,как это работает, вникните в то, как работает виртуальная машина и происходит выделение памяти. Насколько я понял из Вашего профиля Вы специалист по С++. Там не много различий.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов, а ведь @VladD прав, чтобы добиться happens-before нужно сделать что-то вроде list = list; только в этом случае можно говорить о корректной работе. JMM не гарантирует happens-before для элементов массива. Это вам стоит внимательнее изучить эту тему.

Comment: list = list - такую строчку Java даже "не заметит". Оптимизатор просто "выкинет" ее из кода программы. Можете это проверить, написав подобную конструкцию и поставив на нее точку останова. Она не сработает. 

Вспомним, что по сути ссылка на массив - это ссылка на его первый элемент, а все остальные идут непрерывно за ним (в адресном пространстве). Теперь в чем суть проблемы. В целях оптимизации, Java создает локальную копию массива в другом потоке. Т.е. копирует весь массив, и поэтому изменения, вносимые в дочернем потоке, не видны в основном. Избежать этого позволяет volatile.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов: Массив с его элементами — да, но не ссылка на массив. Подумайте об этом. Массив в Java — **ссылочный тип**. Насчёт локальной копии массива — не смешите: локально кэшируется лишь ссылка на массив, копированием потенциально огромного массива никто заниматься не будет.

У вас `volatile` лишь ссылка на массив, но сам не массив.

Если считаете, что я не прав — с вас опровергающая меня ссылка на документацию.

Comment: Я с удовольствием подискутирую с Вами по этому поводу. Мне необходимо пару дней для того, чтобы покопаться в документации и/или провести исследование в рамках JVM.

Но признайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы тот факт, что добавление volatile в данный конкретный пример делает его рабочим. Поверьте, я написал ответ на этот вопрос не от фонаря, а скопировал текст программы и убедился, что без volatile не работает, а с volatile - работает.

Comment: @Алексей Шаповалов: Я согласен с вами насчёт того, что такой код работает. Моё утверждение состоит лишь в том, что ваш код _имеет право_ не работать, например, если memory view одного из потоков будет отличаться от memory view другого (например, на многопроцессорной системе). То есть, мне кажется, ваш код всё ещё содержит race condition.

Comment: Мне кажется (это просто логично, *поскольку отвечает ожиданиям* большинства программеров), что компилятор Java (по аналогии с gcc (понимаю, что выглядит это странновато...))

"проецирует" квалификатор `volatile` c указателя (ссылки на объект в Java) на адресуемую им память.

--

Кстати (см. gcc -S -O3 ...), в коде

    int x = 1;
    volatile int *p = &x;

    while (*p);

`volatile` будет относиться именно к `x` (!!!), а вот в коде

    int x = 1;
    int * volatile  p = &x;
    ...
 
`volatile` будет и сам указатель и память, которую он адресует в данный момент.

Comment: @avp: В C `volatile int * p` читается как «`p` — указатель на `volatile int`». В Java же [не так](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.de/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html):

> The first lesson to learn, which will guide us here, is that `arr` **is a volatile reference to an array, not a reference to an array of volatile elements**! As a result, the write to `arr[0]` is not a volatile write. If you write to `arr[0]`, you will get none of the ordering or visibility guarantees that you want from a volatile write.

Comment: @avp: Таким образом, объявление `volatile`, на мой взгляд, лишь затруднило жизнь оптимизатору, но не гарантирует видимости изменений в другом потоке. На x86 [это не важно](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/14/229387.aspx) (т. к. физически память работает более «тупо»), а вот уже на многопроцессорном x64 или Itanium возможны проблемы.

Comment: Интересно, что на http://ideone.com/y5eQOa успешно выполняется независимо не только от `volatile`, но и от наличия `sleep` в `Counter `.

Comment: @avp: Там всё же выполняется в sandbox'е, поэтому вполне возможно, что на одном ядре. В этом случае проблем может и не быть.

Comment: @VladD, причем здесь несколько ядер?

Дело ведь в том, что тут важна синхронизация памяти уже **после завершения потока**. Очевидно, что рано или поздно данные из кэша любого ядра будут переписаны в RAM (кроме случая, когда по завершению потока мы принудительно очистим кэш).
 
Я почитал про JMM и проч. и не обнаружил ничего подобного. С другой стороны, про завершение потока как точку синхронизации (в отличие от *intrinsic lock*), тоже ничего не нашел.

Конечно, еще тут нужно учитывать, когда main перечитывает значение `list[50]` из RAM.

--

Ситуация остается для меня загадочной (limit...)

Comment: @avp: Не совсем: если обновлённое значение в рабочем потоке не считается, `while` будет бежать вечно. Так что завершения потока не будет.

Другое дело, что в данном случае, думаю, решающую роль играет не кэш процессора (иначе не воспроизводилось бы стабильно), а оптимизации, которые выкидывают перепроверку условия как бессмысленную с т. зр. семантики языка.

Comment: @VladD, да, но я так и не понял, программа автора (в вопросе) завершается или нет. 

Мне кажется, это скорее зависит от версии JVM, чем от числа ядер.

Понятно, что если цикл не завершается, значит чтение из памяти в главном потоке выброшено.

Возможно, все-таки у @Алексей Шаповалов volatile влияет на чтение (может быть, после завершения какого-либо потока это чтение происходит).

А в моих экспериментах на ideon (с печатью внутри while в главном потоке), похоже, оно происходит постоянно. 

--

(Вот это уже 4-й комментарий.)

Comment: @avp: Автор в комментарии к вопросу пишет, что строка вывода после цикла «не срабатывает». Это, судя по всему, означает, что у него цикл крутится бесконечно.

---
Для сложных технических проблем четырёх комментариев явно недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, он работает и кушает циклы процессора в пустую, пока истинно условие самого цикла. Работу цикла можно проверить добавлением всего лишь одной строки: System.out.println("I'm working, dude!");

Comment: при завершении цикла, должен сработать: for (int x:list) System.out.print(x + " ");

В свою очередь, если добавить в цикл любой код(как например в нашем случае "System.out.println("I'm working, dude!")"), то цикл начнет работать

Comment: @Disabled77: Э, не. Вы должны засинхронизировать обращение к переменной из разных потоков. Иначе оптимизатор имеет право вас наказать за недостаточное курение документации и непонимание Java Memory Model.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, кинуть ссылку почитать? Т.к. я об этом совсем ничего не знаю.

Comment: @Disabled77: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Вкратце: окружайте доступ к разделяемой между потоками переменной блоками `synchronized(о)`. Не забудьте, что этот самый `o` обязан быть одним и тем же во всех потоках, которые работают с переменной. (Например, может подойти `Counter.class`.)

Comment: @Disabled77: Вот ещё: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model (неожиданно, да?)